# jquery tablesorter sorting numbers incorrectly

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

My table has a column of numbers which are sorted incorrectly.

```
Example numbers:
5.8
2.4
10.7
0.1
1.9
```

and basically my problem is 10.7 should be at the very end/very start depending on which way it was sorted. but it is showing up in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually specifying the column parser. You can do this easily via metadata -- indicating the parser type in the class of the table header for the column in question. For example:

```
<th class="{sorter: 'floating'}">
```

Further reading:

- [Setting parsers with metadata](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-parsers.html)
- [List of available parsers](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/09/29/jquery-tablesorter-list-of-builtin-parserssorters/) (Tablesorter's own documentation is weak on this. Of course you can also look at the source.)
- [Writing a custom parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)

Answer (score 0):

See Ken's answer, but note that 'floating' no longer exists in newer versions (and neither does 'integer'). You now need to use **'digit'** instead.

```
ts.addParser({
  id: "digit",
  is: function (s, table) {
    var c = table.config;
    return $.tablesorter.isDigit(s, c);
  }, format: function (s) {
    return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s);
  }, type: "numeric"
});
```